# I only want to import the last 3 days of text files into Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a folder with over 16,000 files and I've managed to find some code that won't break Excel when it searches all of the files. Now I need some code that will import the last 3 days worth of text files. Any help would be appreciated.

Current code:

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range
Dim dateToCheck As Date
Dim daysBack As Integer
Dim filesCheckd As Integer

filesChecked = 0
daysBack = 5
dateToCheck = DateAdd("d", -daysBack, Date)

Dim StrFile As String
StrFile = Dir("X:\TMS\TRUCK_OUT\")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
 filesChecked = filesChecked + 1
 StrFile = Dir
Loop

MsgBox filesChecked

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to use the file's **Creation Date** as the criteria ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Yes, I think that should work best.

Comment: Look up `FileDateTime Function`.  This function gives you the file property to need.

Comment: @TonyDallimore  Would you have time to show me how to add that to the above code? I know next to nothing when it comes to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I told you the function to use and your response was to ask me to explain how to use it.  The implication is that you know so little about Excel VBA that even knowing which function to use is not enough to add two extra statements to your code.

You must invest some time in learning the basics of Excel VBA.  Trying to get a macro written for you without knowing the basics will probably fail.  If you are successful, it will take a long time if you are only going to get a few lines per question.

Search the internet for "Excel VBA tutorial".  There are many to choose from.  Alternatively, visit a good bookshop or library and look for Excel VBA Primers.  Again many to choose from.  The time you invest in learning the basics will very quickly repay itself.

**Issue 1**

The first declaration is `Dim fso As FileSystemObject`.  This will only compile if one of your references is for the `Microsoft Scripting RunTime`.  You do not use fso.  Are you planning to use it later?  Why have you used Dir rather than the Files property of the folder object you have declared?

**Issue 2**

What do you mean by: "I've managed to find some code that won't break Excel when it searches all of the files."  What code did you have which broke Excel?

**Issue 3**

`Dim daysBack As Integer` declares a 16-bit integer.  Unless you have an old 16-bit computer, this will require extra processing.  `Dim i As Long` declares a 32-bit integer and it the correct choice.

**Issue 4**

`Dir` returns a Variant.  `Dir$` returns a String and is faster.

None of the above issues are immediately important.  I trying to show some of the little things you do not know about Excel VBA and the traps waiting to catch you when you do not know the basics.

For the version of your macro below, I have:

- Indented the code to make it easier to read.
- Commented out statements you do not current use.
- Added two statements so only files with a Last Modified Date after `dateToCheck` are counted.

This will take you a little further.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()

  'Dim fso As FileSystemObject
  'Dim folder As folder
  'Dim file As file
  'Dim FileText As TextStream
  'Dim TextLine As String
  'Dim Items() As String
  'Dim i As Long
  'Dim cl As Range
  Dim dateToCheck As Date
  Dim daysBack As Integer
  Dim filesCheckd As Integer
  Dim StrFile As String

  Dim PathRoot As String

  filesChecked = 0
  daysBack = 5
  dateToCheck = DateAdd("d", -daysBack, Date)

  PathRoot = "X:\TMS\TRUCK_OUT\"

  StrFile = Dir$(PathRoot)
  Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    If FileDateTime(PathRoot & StrFile) < dateToCheck Then
      filesChecked = filesChecked + 1
    End If
    StrFile = Dir$
  Loop

  MsgBox filesChecked

  'Set FileText = Nothing
  'Set file = Nothing
  'Set folder = Nothing
  'Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```